# Rails 4, multiple file upload on AWS S3 using jQuery-File-Upload using minimum amount of resources

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I know that the topic of uploading files with rails is a quite frequent one on SO, but I am asking myself some questions to which I couldn't find answers.

I try to allow the users of my app to upload multiple files with the very polished jQuery-File-Upload (JQFU for the rest of the post) and store them directly on AWS S3.
The result I would like to achieve is the one that will use the minimum amount of resources (storage, CPU...) on the machine hosting my rails app.

After some investigation, it appears that many people use either carrierwave or paperclip. But I am afraid that it consumes too much resources on the hosting machine.

Also, there is the very good (as always) railscast #383 and a gem `s3_direct_upload`, that uses only JQFU to upload multiple files to AWS S3, which seems to be the best fit for my goal, unfortunately it uses JQFU's basic setup and is quite outdated.

I would like to have the nice views with the progress bars and buttons like in the [demo site](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

So in the first place, are my assumptions just flat out wrong? Then, if someone already managed to get `s3_direct_upload` to work in the way I described above, please provide some guidance to explain how you achieved it.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks shabeer90 for your nice touch.